# Accessing historical data for validators from the API

Tags: external-api, validators, beacon-chain, data

I have been trying to pull the validator-level data for ETH for a project I am working on. I am using [this API](https://beaconcha.in/api/v1/docs/index.html#/Validator/get_api_v1_validator_stats__index_) and have been unable to find a command I need. Ideally, the request URL would either return the number of validators for each day/era/epoch (any of those work) or even better, would return validator-level information for each validator staking during each day/era/epoch. I see requests for current validator information, but I can't see how to access historical data.

Does anyone know of a request URL that would work for this or another API that would have this information? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the **'Ethereum Beacon API Node'**, in their documentation on [ethereum.github.io](https://ethereum.github.io/beacon-APIs/#/).

> All requests by default send and receive `JSON`, and as such should have either or both of the "Content-Type, and in addition, some requests can return data in the **SSZ format**. To indicate that **SSZ data** is required in response to a request the header accept.

You can check '**Validators**' and '**Validator required API**' at the same time.

[image]

**API endpoints** are individually versioned. As such, all `JSON` responses return the requested data under a data key in the top level of their response. Additional metadata may or may not be present in other keys at the top level of the response, dependent on the endpoint.